# node.js on production server

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I have written a website in angular2 and deploy the **dist** folder ( after compiling using webpack) on the AWS server. website works just fine. Now I am wondering why ?? because I have not installed **node.js** on the server neither I have deployed the **node_modules** folder than how come the website works just fine.  In my VS code, I have to download packages using npm but on server, no package exist. kindly explain. It may sound a strange question but I am really confused Or missing some basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you are creating your distribution folder by running a command similar to npm run build:prod all your code including required packages and libraries are compressed into minified files which is eventually deployed to the server. So thats how all your node_modules are still part of your code in the dist folder.

Comment: we get 5 files in the dist folder but seems the inline.js is the one which loads rest of the files. it seems this inline file needs webpack after looking into the code in the file.  Can you please throw some light on it ?? as webpack is not even there on the prod server.

Comment: @user2225263 i just commented another answer on this post to make it more descriptive for you ☺️

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not run on the server, but on the client instead.

The server simply sends the files to the client, so they can be run.

Therefore you really need nothing installed on the server. It is just there for delivery of the files.

EDIT: I guess it's worth mentioning that there is some tanspile/compile/pack steps that can happen on the server to make the distribution package `readable` by the clients javascript.

Comment: Shuja Ahmed  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete breakdown of files that are created after you run npm run build:prod:

1. dist/main.[hash].bundle.js Your application bundled.
2. dist/vendor.[hash].bundle.js Your dependencies (@angular, RxJS...) bundled
3. dist/polyfill.[hash].bundle.js the polyfill dependencies (@angular, RxJS...) bundled .
4. dist/index.html entry point of your application.
5. dist/inline.[hash].bundle.js webpack loader
6. dist/style.[hash].bundle.css the style definitions
7. dist/assetsresources copied from the Angular CLI assets configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I actually see those files in my dist and I understand each one except the webpack loader. may be my knowledge about webpack is not up the the mark but when I open and see the inline.js file, I do see an IIFE just like jquery but how it is loading all modules and how come it has no dependency as the code does not look like a plain javascript code as in the case of jQuery.

Comment: Well thats how any loader works, compressing your dependencies into small chunks ready for deployment on production server. Try googling for loaders and webpack loader in particular to read more about how these loaders work.